# SQLAlchemy - only one result being returned when count() says there are more

Tags: python, database, select, sqlalchemy

I'm having trouble with a really large result set only returning one row.

```
Session.query(TestSet).join(Instance).count()
>> 4283878
Session.query(TestSet).join(Instance).offset(0).limit(100).count()
>> 100
Session.query(TestSet).join(Instance).offset(0).limit(100).all()
>> [<model.testset.TestSet object at 0x043EC2F0>]
```

That is, `all` returns only *one* instance of my model, instead of 100.  Now, for something even stranger:

```
len(Session.query(TestSet).join(Instance).offset(0).limit(100).distinct().all())
>> 100
```

So if I add `distinct` before `all`, I get back all 100 results.  What's going on here?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `Query` object, when asked to iterate through results representing an entity like `TestSet`, performs uniquing on the result rows based on object identity, so that if the query were to return 100 rows each with the same `TestSet` primary key, you'd get only one result object back.  This behavior has its origins in the "eager joining" feature of `Query`, where it's often the case that many result rows are being received each with the same primary identity, but also containing a varying secondary identity of a related row that's to be populated into a collection upon each primary identity - only one instance of the primary identity is desirable in this very common case.

Let's then consider what `distinct()` does.  Suppose your query for 4M objects returns 1000 rows with id=1, 1000 rows with id=2, etc.   The query with limit(100) hits the first 100 rows with id=1, `Query` uniquifies, and you get one result object back, since they are all id=1.  But with `distinct()`, suddenly we are getting 100 rows with distinct identities, i.e. "id=1", "id=2", "id=3".   `Query` then assigns each of these rows to a new `TestSet` object in the identity map, and you get 100 rows back.

Setting `echo='debug'` on your `Engine` temporarily will show the SQL being emitted as well as the result rows coming back.   When you see many result rows all with the same primary key, you know that `Query` when asked to return full entities is going to unique all those redundant identities down to the single object represented for each row.

Comment: Life saver explanation (was stuck in same problem for quite some time). My mistake was that I declared wrong column as 'primary_key' during the Table declaration. So, the ORM clubbed (grouped) uniquely my result rows to only 1 row.