# SQLAlchemy - Different counts of list with same queries?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

is possible to get two different counts of list from same query with filters?

First query:

```
subjects = Subject.query.filter(
    and_(
    ...
    ...
).order_by(Subject.name).slice(0, 10).count()
```

#

```
print('count', subjects)
count 10
```

Second query:

```
subjects = Subject.query.filter(
    and_(
    ...(same filters)
    ...
).order_by(Subject.name).slice(0, 10).all()
```

#

```
print('len', len(subjects))
len 6
```

(Of course, DB is same.)

Hm, do you have idea whats wrong?

Comment: Can you provide an example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: This is a fairly common question. Here are some dupe candidates/related Q/A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435346/sqlalchemy-different-value-from-lenquery-all-and-query-count, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704961/sqlalchemy-union-all-and-all-returning-incorrect-number-of-items

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933478/sqlalchemy-only-one-result-being-returned-when-count-says-there-are-more

Comment: @Ilja Everilä thanks for your hint. Now it works fine. Please, add your comment as Answer and i will accept it.